# Is there a scroll function python code for appium

Tags: python, function, scroll, appium

Trying to use appium on python, to use a scroll function but when I put the coordinates of the place where I want to swipe from (from xy to xy). Everytime I use this function it does random distances. Is there any other ways to get it to accurately scroll down. (Driver.find.flick this is the code that I used and it just flicks rather than
accurately scrolling.)

Thanks